# height is not divisible by 2 ffmpeg how I could solve this?

Tags: linux, image, ffmpeg

i use this code but not works

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpeg' -c:v libx264   -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

and also use this code too and not wotks

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpeg' -c:v libx264   -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4  -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"
```

please help me

Comment: `not works` is not a description of the problem. You need to elaborate what exactly don't work. If you got an error message - add that message into the question post.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placement of option matters.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpeg' -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Filters for streams have to be specified before the output filename they're meant for.